# Return color value into a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I return color value into a variable using if-else statement in a function then use the function in `charts_flutter` dependencies?

Error prompt in the IDE are:
"only static members can access in initializers" for 
monthlyExpenses: expensesJan,
barColor: getChartColor(monthlyExpenses),

Thank you

```dart
  double monthlyExpenseLimit = 400.00;
  double expenseJan = 800.00;
  Color getChartColor(double monthlyExpenses){

    Color barColor;

    if(monthlyExpenses <= 0.8*monthlyExpenseLimit){
      barColor = Colors.green;
    }

    else if(monthlyExpenses <= monthlyExpenseLimit && monthlyExpenses >= monthlyExpenseLimit){
      barColor = charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.yellow);
    }

    else{
      barColor = Colors.red;
    }

    return barColor;
  }

  final List<MonthlyExpensesSeries> data = [
    MonthlyExpensesSeries(
      month: "JAN",
      monthlyExpenses: expenseJan,
      barColor: getChartColor(monthlyExpenses),
    ),
  ];
```

Comment: You are going to need to ask something a little more specific.

Comment: you need to define `getChartColor` as static.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you want to do is create a function that simply returns a color in Flutter, and pass that color into [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter#-readme-tab-)

To do this, you simply create a [color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html) variable, `color` and assign it based on your if/else statement. Sample code below:

```dart
Color getColor(bool isRed) {
  //red is just a sample color
  Color color;
  if(isRed) {
    color = Colors.red;
  } else {
    color = Colors.blue;
  }
  return color;
}
```

and then when you want to use the function, when the field for color is requested, simply supply your function like so:

```dart
//...
color: getColor(true),
//...
```

I hope I answered your question, and if I didn't just add a comment and I will adjust my answer.

---

**Edit:**
According to your new code, you must define your `getColor` method as static

Answer (score 0):

Me too wanted to return color to backgroundColor which is in Scaffold, so what I did was :

```
backgroundColor: changeColor(currentWidth,currentHeight),
```

Where changeColor is method and return color, which is then set to background color. I used if-else statement in the method and return the color as per the condition.

```
myChangeColor(double currentWidth,double currentHeight) {
    if(currentWidth<600 && currentHeight<600){
      Color c = const Color(0xFF42A5F5);
      return c;
    }else if(currentWidth<400 || currentHeight<400){
      Color c =  Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
      return c;
    }else if(currentWidth>500 || currentHeight>500){
      Color color1 = Colors.greenAccent;
      return color1;
    }
  }
```